# Problemas con NGINX y PHP

Tags: php, nodejs, codeigniter, nginx

Buenas, estoy trabajando en un proyecto personal, el tema es el siguiente, la aplicación en sí está montada en `NodeJS` por temas de que requiero usar `Socket.io` y la aplicación se conecta con una `API` REST en `PHP` `CodeIgniter` por temas de comodidad en cuanto al código, la misma se encuentra alojada en el mismo servidor, el tema es el siguiente:

Por el momento pude lograr que funcione la `API` ya que si entro en `misitio.com/api/loquesea` me lo ejecuta bien, el tema es que al ingresar al sitio en la raiz `misitio.com/` el sitio que está hecho en `NodeJS` con `Angular` no me muestra nada, ya que el servidor intenta parsearlo como si fuera `CodeIgniter` devolviendome un `error 404` cada vez que carga un `js`.

Por ejemplo, este es el código que tengo en este momento. Todo esto está montado en `NGINX`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name misitio.com;
    root /home/misitio.com/;

    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_redirect off;
    }

    if ($request_uri ~ ^api/index/?$){
            rewrite ^/(.*)api/index/?$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    if (!-d $request_filename){
            rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    if ($request_uri ~ ^api/system){
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ /api/index.php?/$1 last;
            break;
    }

    if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
            break;
    }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/misitio.com/api$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht{
            deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: Y si en lugar de una ruta (conflictiva), haces accesible la API en un subdominio tipo api.ejemplo.com. De este modo tendrías bloques separados sin conflicto de rutas.

Comment: @JesúsFranco lo estaba armando asi debido a que ahora estoy sin ningun dominio, era con la IP directamente, no obstante ya logré solucionarlo por otros medios.

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir tu solución? Así podríamos beneficiarnos de tu aprendizaje, y podría ser incluso referencia para otras preguntas en el futuro, además también te daría puntos de reputación que te permiten desbloquear posibilidades de interacción en stackoverflow :-)

Comment: Ya está agregada la configuración que estoy utilizando.

Comment: @leiteszeke podrías agregar tu solución como una respuesta, así es más fácil de ver. Si es posible también agrega una explicación de como funciona tu solución. ¿Nginx sirve la solución en PHP y el Apache la que está en nodejs? No me queda claro. Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno, la solución funciona de la siguiente forma, tengo Nginx corriendo en el puerto 80 y Apache en el 8080. Tengo configurado el servidor en nginx, que es por donde entra... Al entrar a misitio.com, hago un reverse proxy a misitio.com:3000 que es donde tengo corriendo mi aplicación en NodeJS. Al entrar a misitio.com/api hago un proxy a localhost:8080 que es donde esta corriendo Apache desde ese momento, empieza a correr el VirtualHost de Apache que es el que me deriva a lo que estoy pidiendo, en este caso, estaria buscando el contenido de /var/www/api/.

Intente hacerlo de la forma inversa, Apache en Puerto 80 y NGINX en otro, pero no logré resultados.

```
    server { 
          listen 80 default_server; 
          listen [::]:80 default_server;
          server_name misitio.com www.misitio.com;

          root /var/www;
          index index.php index.html index.htm;

          location ~ ^/(images/|img/|assets/|templates/|photos/|javascript/|js/|css/|stylesheets/|flash/|media/|static/|robots.txt|humans.txt|favicon.ico) {
                   root /var/www/ygobattlecity/public;
                   access_log off;
                   expires max;
          }

          location / {
                   proxy_pass http://misitio.com:3000;
                   proxy_redirect off;
          }

          location /api {
                   proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
                   include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
          }

          location ~* \.(js|css|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|ico|pdf|html|htm)$ {
                   expires      30d;
          }

          location ~* \.php$ {
                   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                   include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
          }
   }

  <VirtualHost *:8080>
           ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost 
           ServerName misitio.com 
           ServerAlias www.misitio.com 
           DocumentRoot /var/www

           ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
           CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

           <Directory />
                   Options FollowSymLinks
                   AllowOverride None
           </Directory>

           <Directory /var/www/>
                   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                   AllowOverride All
                   Order allow,deny
                   allow from all
          </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
```